# Issue with s-function in simulink test sequence

Tags: unit-testing, simulink

Upon trying to test a test sequence/ test harness (using a test case manager), I get the following error in the test case manager window:

```
Cannot register run-time parameter for dialog parameter 1 for S-function 'sf_sfun' in <test_sequence> because the dialog parameter is empty
```

Which is interesting because I'm definitely not including any s functions in the test sequence (nor do I know how to). I've compared it to a test case that does indeed work, and I can't find any discrepancy.

Not really sure how to navigate around this issue.